# Protractor wait for Angular to load

Tags: angularjs, protractor, sleep, angularjs-e2e

my test is doing login in a non-angular page, and then getting to an Angular page.
currently, in order for the test to work properly I'm using sleep and timeout (right after the login):

```
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
flow.timeout(5000);
```

I've tried removing each one of them, and tried also Expected condition:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var profilePhoto = element(By.css(".profile-photo"));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(profilePhoto), 15000);
```

tried also using the

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

but - any try without the sleep and timeout resulted in failure and

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
```

my question is -how can I make sure I got to the home page (after login) without 'sleep' or 'timeout'?

Comment: When you are in a non-angular page use - `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` and when you are in an angular page, use `false`. Have you tried doing this? Thanks

Comment: yes, you can see the 'false' on the snippet I've put. the 'false' is on the 'on prepare'.

Comment: I meant are you changing that value, when you switch to a non-angular page?

Comment: I switch from non-angular to angular, so it is first 'browser.ignoreSynchronization = true' and after clicking the 'login' I'm setting 'browser.ignoreSynchronization = false' as you can see on first snippet.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue. I am using Angular 2.0 beta 13.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier today.  Adding `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` just before the login attempt and adding `browser.wait...` just after the login attempt fixed the problem:

```
// non-angular page
browser.get("/login");

// ignore synchronization since we're transitioning from a non-angular page to an angular page
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

// login
element(by.id("email")).sendKeys("username");
element(by.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
element(by.partialButtonText("Login")).click();

// wait
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("dashboard"))), 10000);
```

Comment: still getting the same error. although it seems like the position of the 'browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;' doesn't affect the results.

Comment: I'm using angular v1.5.0-rc.0 and protractor v2.5.1 and asp.net mvc on the non-angular login page.

Comment: did you set browser.ignoreSynchronization back to false after login?